# generator raised StopIteration

Tags: python, translation

I have a block of code designed to translate from english to other languages. However, it keeps failing and gives the error in the heading.

```
from translate import Translator

def read_entries_from_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        entries = file.read().splitlines()
    return entries

def translate_entries_to_french(entries):
    translator = Translator(to_lang="french")
    translated_entries = []
    for entry in entries:
        key, _, text_to_translate = entry.partition('=')
        
        if text_to_translate.strip():
            try:
                translation = translator.translate(text_to_translate.strip())
                translated_entry = f"{key}={translation}"
                translated_entries.append(translated_entry)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error translating text: {text_to_translate.strip()}")
                print(f"Error details: {str(e)}")
                translated_entries.append(f"{key}=Translation Error")
        else:
            translated_entries.append(entry)
    return translated_entries
if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = r'<---my file--->'  # Update with your file path
    entries_to_translate = read_entries_from_file(file_path)
    translated_entries = translate_entries_to_french(entries_to_translate)
    for translated_entry in translated_entries:
        print(translated_entry)
```

Comment: If the error is in Translator (check the traceback), you should contact its author or support site.